# return calculation using newly generated column values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have change column and i want result column as output.(1+change)*100 for 1st result row is fixed  but on words (1+ change)* result from previous row 
for 2nd row: (1+(-0.0106))*100.87
i have done with loops. but i am trying with lambda function so that i can pass array of values  and i will get array of result.

```
change        result

                 100
0.0087         100.87    
-0.0106      99.800778    
0.0133      101.1281283    
0.0527      106.4575807    
0.0269      109.3212896    
-0.014      107.7907916    
-0.0247     105.128359    
-0.012     103.8668187    
0.0494     108.9978396    
0.0092     110.0006197    
-0.0278    106.9426025    
0.0162     108.6750726
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: what is 100 in **result** column and it's corresponding **change** is Null?

Comment: 100 is included only for 1st row..for simplicity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a cumulative product of the changes:

```
df['result'] = 100 * (df.change + 1).cumprod()
```

Comment: Really nice answer ;)